# Kohana 3.2 session expires too soon, shorter expirations work as expected

Tags: php, session, kohana, kohana-3.2

Kohana 3.2 sessions are expiring too soon. My current config is:

```
return array(
'native' => array(
    'name' => 'kohanasession',
    'lifetime' => 0,       
 ),
);
```

Using `lifetime => 0` means that the session will end when the browser is closed. However, after 1 hour, the session expires.

I also tried to use a lifetime different (for example 36000 => 10 hours), but again, it failed.

If I use a tiny session life (e.g. 10 seconds) then the expiration works perfectly. As far as I checked, seems that if I want a session to have a lifetime longer than 1 hour, it will not work.

Finally, the relevant config we use for php.ini

```
session.save_handler = memcache
session.save_path="tcp://127.0.0.1:11211?persistent=1&weight=1&timeout=1&retry_interval=15"
session.cache_limiter = nocache
session.gc_probability = 0
```

I am really lost here. This should be simple to fix but I just cannot work it out.

Comment: Try to work with session without Kohana Session library (create a simple PHP-script). It will help you to decide, is it a Kohana problem, or its a server issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `lifetime => 0` parameter is likely only affecting the session cookie's lifetime.

What's probably happening is that, while the cookie is working fine, you're throwing away the users' session data on the server side. PHP has session garbage collection that's a little odd by default: it marks sessions as expired after 24 minutes of idle time, and has a 1% chance on each request to clean up all the expired sessions.

You can increase the PHP ini setting `session.gc_maxlifetime`, or you could set `session.gc_probability` to zero to disable automatic session garbage collection entirely.

Of course, there's also the possibility that your memcached server is configured to throw away the data after some time period.

**Update:** For the *average* session handler, setting `session.gc_probability` to zero would be the way to go to disable the automatic cleanup entirely. However, the memcache session handler actually already doesn't do garbage collection (its gc callback does nothing). So, changing either of `session.gc_probability` or `session.gc_divisor` is pointless with that save handler.

Instead, the memcache save handler automatically sets an expiration when saving the session data to the memcached server (a la the `expire` param to [Memcache::set](http://www.php.net/manual/en/memcache.set.php)). The handler reads the expiration time to use from the `session.gc_maxlifetime` setting. So, *that's* the only GC setting that really matters when you're using the memcache session save handler.

Comment: Unfortunately that is not working, after setting the gc_probability to 0, the problem persists.

Comment: My bad. Peeking at [the memcache extension's source](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/pecl/memcache/trunk/memcache_session.c?view=markup) it's apparent that the "normal" session GC code doesn't get used with the memcache handler. Instead, the handler automatically sets an `expire` param equal to `session.gc_maxlifetime` when storing the data. Increasing the maxlifetime should definitely work, as *should* setting the maxlifetime to 0.